# Homebrew and MongoDB Installation

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am currently having a problem to install Homebrew on my mac (macOS Mojave 10.14.5). It says that the installation may not succeed and not supported for old version macOS. Because of that, I've failed to install MongoDB too.

Anyone can help me? Really need to use MongoDB as soon as possible for my next class.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you follow [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)?

Comment: If you need it quick and easy for learning then the Shared Mongo Atlas (i.e. MongoDB Cloud Service) could be an option: https://www.mongodb.com/pricing

Comment: MongoDB 5.0 Community Edition supports macOS 10.14 or later - so it should work.